# MySQL Select IF INNER JOIN

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have 3 tables:

```
place (placeId,placeName,...)
event (eventId, eventName,...)
picture (pictureId,associateId,picturePath,type [1 place 2 event])
```

This is what I want:

When picture type is 1 picture.associateId=place.placeId return path

when picture type is 2 picture.associateId=event.eventId return path

1 place -> many events

1 place -> one picture

1 event -> one picture

May be something like this (please help):

```
SELECT Place.placeName, Picture.picturePath, Event.eventId, ... FROM Place INNER JOIN Event ON Place.placeId = Event.eventPlace INNER JOIN Picture ON (IF Picture.type=1 return Picture.picturePath ELSE Picture.type=2 return Picture.picturePath)
```

This consult return me a json to show events on a page deppending of the date:

```
SELECT Place.placeName, Place.placePopularity, Picture.picturePath, Event.eventId, Event.eventCount
FROM Place INNER JOIN Picture ON Place.placeId = Picture.associateId 
    INNER JOIN Event ON Place.placeId = Event.eventPlace
WHERE Picture.type = 2 AND Event.eventDate = '$date'
ORDER BY Event.eventCount DESC
```

Comment: add your tables with SHOW CREATE TABLE please

Comment: 1 place can have many events, 1 place/event can have only 1 picture

Comment: Please provide some sample data for all three tables. Also, please show us what you would expect the output of your SQL to be if you were to run it on that sample data.

Comment: I've tried to format your question, but it is still incomprehensible to me, particularly the "this is what I want" section. Please try to use round sentences - it is not a problem if your English isn't very good, although following at least [these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) spelling rules could improve your posts a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Run an `if else` with this

```
    if () { // picture type 1
        // this is the query
        $query = "SELECT pictureTable.picture_path FROM placeTable INNER JOIN picture_table ON placeTable.placeId = picture_table.associateId";
        } else { // picture type 2 means for event

        $query = "SELECT pictureTable.picture_path FROM eventTable INNER JOIN  picture_table ON eventTable.eventId = picture_table.associateId";
       // now you can get the result
       }
```

Hope this helps.